# last array value coming blank?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

my array is (coming from database)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-12 [user_id] => 48 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-31 [user_id] => 77 ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-03 [user_id] => 318 ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-20 [user_id] => 619 ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-21 [user_id] => 619 ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-25 [user_id] => 619 ) [6] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-28 [user_id] => 619 ) [7] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-11 [user_id] => 747 ) [8] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-12 [user_id] => 747 ) [9] => Array ( [date] => 2011-05-29 [user_id] => 747 ) [count] => 10 )
```

and when i use

```
foreach($appVenueAmbassador as $kk => $venueUserId){

            $unique[] = $appVenueAmbassador[$kk]['user_id'];

        }
```

on that query then i get

```
Array ( [0] => 48 [1] => 77 [2] => 318 [3] => 619 [4] => 619 [5] => 619 [6] => 619 [7] => 747 [8] => 747 [9] => 747 [10] => )
```

means last element is coming blank
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because the last element is `[count] => 10` and doesn't have a `user_id`. You should be seeing a warning regarding this if you'd switch on error reporting. Also, the way you're grabbing that value is quite overcomplicated. Try this:

```
foreach ($appVenueAmbassador as $venue){
   if (isset($venue['user_id'])) {
       $unique[] = $venue['user_id'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the key is a number before using it, or remove the `count` index from the array before processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve your problem

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < $appVenueAmbassador['count']; $i++) {
     $unique[] = $appVenueAmbassador[$i]['user_id'];
  }

?>
```

It will not use the last key `count`